# How to run applications using admin account while it is not in use or active?

Tags: administration

I want to have applications running (like deluge) in admin account even if admin account is not active and guest or family account is in use.

Some times family account is in use and pc is restarted for any reason so admin app won't start on the background.

Is there a ways to make this  possible?

Comment: Why are you running a BitTorrent client with admin privileges?

Comment: your question is not clear, do you want to have an application to automatically running when the computer is started ?

Comment: @ændrük: I would guess that it's not so much about the privileges as having it run as a daemon even if his own account isn't logged in.

Answer (score 1):

This website has some nice articles on setting up a media server, one of which is for a deluge daemon:
http://havetheknowhow.com/Install-the-software/Install-Deluge-Headless.html

note: this ends up creating another user called 'deluge' and having the deluge daemon process running under that user, along with its permissions only.  This way, you don't have to give up root access!